# Why FileStream.Close() hangs for a long time?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, filestream

I'm creating a very big file using a `FileStream` (0.1 - 100 GBytes):

```
using (var strm = File.OpenWrite(Destination)) {
    while(someCondition) {
        bfr = GetBuffer();

        strm.Write(bfr.Data, 0, ChunkSizeInBytes);
        strm.Flush();

        ShowProgress();
    }
}
```

When I get to the end of the `using` statement, the thread hangs for a long time. I put a `strm.Close()` after the loop, and it seems that this is the jamming point (the file closure).

(please note that I `Flush()` after each `Write()`)

Why is it and how to overcome it ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but `Flush(true)` is what flushes it out to disk. `Flush()` will only flush it to an internal buffer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.flush.aspx what may be happening is that Flish() alone doesn't clear intermediate buffer's. So they pile up information that probably is being cleared by the GC at Close(), this last part is a supposition on my part :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comment was correct.

See Hans Passant's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4921728/1517578

`Flush(true)` will flush out to disk immediately. `Flush()` will not.