# Why it copies before writing?

Tags: c#

```
public void AddFile()
    {
        Console.Write("What file to add? : ");
        string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        pathString = Path.Combine(FolderName, MainFolder,fileName);
        
        using StreamWriter file = new(pathString, append: true);
        file.Write("hello world");
        
        
        string source = Path.Combine(FolderName, MainFolder, fileName);
        string dest = Path.Combine(FolderName, SyncFolder, fileName);
        File.Copy(source,dest,true); 
    }
```

Why the last line of the code copies file BEFORE(or at least it acts like that) my file.Write("hello world")?
First launch: file in Main folder has "hello world". file in Sync folder is empty
First launch: file in Main folder has "hello world"x2. file in Sync folder has only one"hello world"
How can i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between FileStream.Flush() and FileStream.Flush(True)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921498/whats-the-difference-between-filestream-flush-and-filestream-flushtrue)

Comment: Flush or Close before doing the copy. Also use the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) keyword for IDisposable pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `using` variable you declared causes the `StreamWriter` to be open until the end of the function which is when the file is written. You have to change it to the following:

```cs
using (StreamWriter file = new(pathString, append: true))
    file.Write("hello world");
```

This way the file will be written to before the file is copied as once the `using` block is over the `StreamWriter` writes the file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `using` line and replace `file.Write` with

```
File.AppendAllText(pathString, "hello world");
```

In future be aware of the difference between these three things:

#### classic `using` multi line block (defined scope)

```
using (var x = new SomeDisposableThing()) {
  using (var y = new OtherDisposableThing()) {
    //x and y are in scope for this 
    //entire block until the
    //next curly bracket below
  }
  //x is in scope, y is disposed
}
```

#### classic `using` single line form

```
using (var x = new SomeDisposableThing()) 
  using (var y = new OtherDisposableThing()) 
    //x and y  in scope for this line only 
//x and y not in scope now and have been disposed
```

#### modern "extended scope" `using`

```
using var x = new SomeDisposableThing();
using var y = new OtherDisposableThing();
//x and y in scope for this 
//entire current block
//perhaps all the way to
//the curly bracket that ends
//the method
```

This latter form is intended to make Code more readable, without suffering lots of indent (when you do db work you might `using` the connection, then the command, then the adapter that the command gives you.. it's a lot of indenting) but you do have to be mindful of how long the variable will live for before it is disposed

Because your variable lived til the end of the method, then was disposed, its most likely the data you appended wasn't flushed to the file at the time you copied the file; it was flushed after

Aim to use the File.XxxText method if you've got a one shot create/write/Append to do- use a streamwriter that you keep ahold of if you have some enduring need to repeatedly write to a file over some amount of time, but if it's a one off, those one liners are handy helper methods