# Does FileStream.FlushAsync() ensure file is written to disk?

Tags: c#, .net-core

On the `FileStream` class, there is a difference between calling `Flush(false)` and `Flush(true)`, the latter will *cause any buffered data to be written to the file*.

However it is not clear what is the behavior of `FlushAsync`, as it doesn't accept a `flushToDisk` parameter.

I suppose my real question is, how can I ensure a file is written to disk, asynchronously?

Comment: Remember, that boolean parameter is about _intermediate_ buffers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4921715/1043380

Comment: Yes, I want to make sure my file is actually on disk and not in OS buffer.

Comment: All the OS can promise is that the disk says it has been written... which may be a lie.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman also true. I have been burned by this before. This is especially true with NAS. On Azure I occasionally found cases of bytes not being written to disk even after the handle was closed .Buried in the event log was a "Delayed Write Error". No .NET exception or any other indication of failure. The only way I ultimately found I could guarantee a successful write was to reopen the file and attempt a read after closure.

Comment: [Disk drives that do not honor sync requests](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_disk_drives_that_do_not_honor_sync_requests) - read this and try not to cry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determining the actual write/flush behavior in .NET Core for disk streams requires a deep dive into the source code, because as pointed out by Jonathan the documentation here is unfortunately inaccurate (or at best highly misleading).

First the behavior depends on if the `FileStream` is opened with buffering (the default) or not. If there's no buffering, the behavior is defined in [OSFileStreamStrategy](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/OSFileStreamStrategy.cs). If it does buffer, it wraps an `OSFileStreamStrategy` in a [BufferedFileStreamStrategy](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs).

Starting with the less common but simpler case of no buffering, see the [FlushAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/OSFileStreamStrategy.cs#L135) override:

```
public sealed override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => 
       Task.CompletedTask; // no buffering = nothing to flush
```

It turns out `FlushAsync` is a no-op in the non-buffering case. The bytes have left the process and are in the hands of the OS now, but the OS has not been independently told to flush the bytes to disk.

Now note the very next lines in that file:

```
internal sealed override void Flush(bool flushToDisk)
{
    if (flushToDisk && CanWrite)
    {
        FileStreamHelpers.FlushToDisk(_fileHandle);
    }
}
```

So not only is `FlushAsync` always a no-op without buffering, but the synchronous `Flush` method is likewise a no-op unless `flushToDisk` is specified. This of course forces a subsequent call to [Win32](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/FileStreamHelpers.Windows.cs#L39) `FlushFileBuffers` or [Unix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/FileStreamHelpers.Unix.cs#L40)'s `fsync`. Thus in the non-buffering case, the simple answer to the question is no, there is no way to ask the OS to write the bytes to the physical disk prior to closing the stream without using the synchronous `Flush(bool flushToDisk)` overload.

As for the more common buffering case, see [FlushAsyncInternal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs#L795). You'll note all this does is call the `OSFileStreamStrategy.WriteAsync`, i.e., it flushes its internal buffers and sends the bytes to the OS, just as if it wasn't buffering, but it doesn't go further and ask the OS to ensure they're written to disk.

The synchronous `Flush(bool flushToDisk)` [overload](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d412f4efdd3215dc2cde7b13f5cc35e2c1e8607/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs#L756) in the buffering case also flushes its buffers to the OS, except synchronously. It then goes further and calls `OSFileStreamStrategy.Flush(flushToDisk)` - which, again, is itself a no-op unless `flushToDisk` is true.

So all of this is a lengthy way of saying that `FlushAsync`, in all cases, only guarantees that bytes have been sent to the operating system, but does not guarantee the operating system has written those bytes to disk. If you want to ask the operating system to do that, you need to call the synchronous `Flush(bool flushToDisk)` overload. (I say "ask" because, even then, there is never a 100% guarantee the bytes are on the hardware, especially in NAS situations).

The best approach, if you want to stay as asynchronous as possible, is therefore to write this:

```
await stream.FlushAsync();
await Task.Run(() => stream.Flush(true));
```

The two lines are actually not redundant! If you call `stream.Flush(true)` without `await stream.FlushAsync()` first, the former will synchronously send its data to the OS, blocking the thread, rather than using the more efficient asynchronous OS write functions. And if you don't use the second line, the OS will not be told to flush its own buffers to disk.

Unfortunately both `FlushFileBuffers` and `fsync` are synchronous, so you will want to wrap `stream.Flush(true)` in the `Task.Run` to avoid blocking the calling thread, but there's no way to do this in a truly asynchronous way at the hardware level (which is rather unfortunate, since at that level of course the write to disk is happening asynchronously).

Answer (score 2):

<s>Yes.</s>

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.flushasync?view=net-8.0) (emphasis mine):

> Asynchronously clears all buffers for this stream, causes any buffered data to be written **to the underlying device**, and monitors cancellation requests.

However, *device* is ambiguous in this context, and based on other comments, apparently only means the OS device handle, and not the actual hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not flush the OS Buffer: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/commit/69a253ecc0e492fc047c92b4368721f4b1e2ae1f 

The docs are confusing in that regards

Comment: Ah. Well it seems inappropriate for the docs to say "written to the underlying device", where "device" could mean the logical *device handle* or the *physical device*. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah agreed, the documentation is just flat out wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [.NET Framework 4.8 source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/5fcc250013100bd8.html), `FlushAsync()` always flushes to disk:

```cs
// Unlike Flush(), FlushAsync() always flushes to disk. This is intentional.
// Legend is that we chose not to flush the OS file buffers in Flush() in fear of 
// perf problems with frequent, long running FlushFileBuffers() calls. But we don't 
// have that problem with FlushAsync() because we will call FlushFileBuffers() in the background.
public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
}
```

Comment: I think they changed this behavior in .Net Core: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/24902

Now FlushAsync behaves such as Flush(false)

Comment: You may want to clarify which .NET version you are using.

Comment: @RedRidingHood: I think you are right. Here is the related [commit info](https://github.com/picenka21/runtime/commit/a123fb2c0a135aa7263f7aeb92e0b67d3917c9c2).

Comment: Yeah that comment in the code is definitely not true for .NET Core. See my answer.